# Multiplos Scheduled Tasks no WSO2

Tags: java, soa, esb

Estou tentando agendar duas tasks no WSO2. Criei os dois arquivos xml na pasta "tasks" no projeto ESB porém apenas uma esta sendo carregada no momento do deploy. 
Estou rodando em apenas um nó. Existem alguma limitação para quantidade de Tasks no WSO2?

Answer (score 1):

Tens certeza que ao criares o ficheiro (Deploying a Carbon Application - **.car**) seleccionas todas as tasks?
..
Clique com o botão direito sobre *Composite Aplication Project* -> *Export Composite Aplication Project* -> *Next*.
Expandir o projecto e selecione as duas tasks e depois botão *Finish*.
E feito isso é so fazer o deploy do ficheiro *.car criado.

Boa Sorte e espero ter ajudado